# Why is value only changed when referenced as calling argument?

Tags: reference

In this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int num1 = 0;
using namespace std;
void add(int &number);
int main()
 {
 int num2;
 int num3;
 add(num1);
 cout << "Num1 is: " << num1 << ". Yep, " << num1 << ".";
 } 
void add(int &number)
 {
 number++;
 }
```

The passed value "num1" to "add" will change it, but in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
    int num1 = 0;
    using namespace std;
    void add(int number);
    int main()
     {
     int num2;
     int num3;
     add(num1);
     cout << "Num1 is: " << num1 << ". Yep, " << num1 << ".";
     } 
    void add(int number)
     {
     number++;
     }
```

It does not change, the value of "num1". Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you increment a COPY of the paramter.  In the first case, with the "reference", you modify the variable itself.

Look up "pass by value vs pass by reference.  For example:

- [Pass by reference](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm)
- [Call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_value#Call_by_value)

It should be noted that C (unlike C++) is always "pass by value" ... but the equivalent can  be achieved by passing a pointer to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case number is a reference to num1. That is that number is reference to the same place in memory num1 refers to. Similar to a pointer but without the hassle of dereferencing it.

In the second number is created in the activation record of add, and placed on the stack. When add terminates the number variable is poped off (and the memory of number is deallocated) the stack, and num1 is left unchanged in main's stack and activation record.

If it were an object and not a primitive, this could be seen in the debugger by where the segfault would occur if you were to manually called the destructor just before add returned.